# Adding angular-datepicker to rails with bower-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, google-maps, bower

Bower-rails looks like it should be turn key, and is for very popular libraries like angular and angular-resource, but how can I add another less popular, but bower enabled, library?

e.g. - https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker, https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

To my Bowerfile I have added

```
asset 'angular-datepicker', github: "g00fy-/angular-datepicker"
```

and run rake bower:install. This installs the files to my vendor/assets/bower_components folder with the other libraries that do work (angular, angular-resource, etc).

But when I add the path to my application.js file, it claims not to be able to find the file.

```
//= require angular-datepicker
```

I've already added the path to the bower_components to my application.rb file

config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')

How can I add these bower libraries to rails?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have to `//= require angular-datepicker/angular-datepicker`

Please checkout https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails/issues/37.